# How can I reduce the number of logs generated by Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

In Azure Functions I want to be able to only log warnings and exceptions coming from Azure.Storage.Blobs but I still want all traces from my code. Is there a way to limit the log level that Azure.Storage.Blobs logs?

I tried adding Blobs to the host.json but that did not seem to have any affect.

```
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Azure.Storage.Blobs": "Warning"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To log the Warning, Exceptions from the NuGet Package `Azure.Storage.Blobs` and traces from the Function Code, below configuration of `host.json` help to get them:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        },
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
      "Azure": "Information",
      "Azure.Storage.Blobs": "Warning",
      
    }
  }
}
```

Here `Function` is set to `Trace` so the `LogTrace()` method can be captured in Application Insights resource.

To get the Warning Level Logs, Log Level attribute should contain the value as `Warning` or higher than `Warning` such as `Information` or `Trace/Verbose` or `Debug`.

Note: Above Configuration Code Snippet is taken from the references MS [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#solutions-with-high-volume-of-telemetry) & [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json).

Comment: Hari, as I show in my example, I do already have Azure.Storage.Blobs set to "Warning" in host.json. However, I am still getting Informational logs from blobs showing up in Azure Insights.

Comment: I have modified the `host.json` code, could you please check with the given code.